# How can i register on dns bind, 2 domains with same ip? Below is the configuration of my dns

Tags: dns, bind

```
zone "zget.com" {

    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.zget.com";

};

//reverse zone

zone "168.192.in-addr.arpa" {

    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.192";

};


;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;

$TTL    604800

@       IN      SOA     ns.zget.com. root.ns.zget.com. (

                             17         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.zget.com.

@       IN      A       192.168.10.13

@       IN      AAAA    ::1

ns      IN      A       192.168.10.13

redmine         IN      A       192.168.10.15


; CNAME SECTION

redmine.zget.com    CNAME   redmine.get.com.

redmine A       192.168.10.15






;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;

$TTL    604800

@       IN      SOA     ns.zget.com. root.ns.zget.com. (

                             15         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.

13       IN      PTR     ns.zget.com.

15

   IN      PTR     redmine.zget.com.
```

When I run the `dig` command on *redmine.zget.com* it will popup its ip on terminal but on *redmine.get.com* the ip did not pop up.

> $ dig redmine.zget.com +short 
>   192.168.10.15

but this one has no response:

> $ dig redmine.get.com +short

I also try to ping the redmine.get.com having also a respond

> $ ping redmine.get.com
>   PING redmine.get.com (192.168.10.15) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from redmine.get.com (192.168.10.15): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.722 ms

Answer (score 0):

Both zones need their own files. At the moment you're defining `redmine.zget.com` to have an A record *and* a CNAME record pointing to `redmine.get.com`. There is nothing there about redmine.get.com being configured to anything.

You have to create another configuration for the `get.com` domain to get this working. The fact that ping is doing something might be due to you having the IP in hosts file, for example.

Comment: The server of redmine.get.com is located at oakland. that have its own dns server. which its domain is get.com. I create a local dns server on our office which its domain is zget.com. They want to redmine.get.com and redmine.zget.com to have same ip.